# Firebase snapshot.key not returning actual key?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that searches for a user based on user ID.

```
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("user exists")
        print(snapshot.key)
```

The query returns the correct user, but the line `print(snapshot.key)` literally returns the word "users", and not an actual user ID. `print(snapshot)` returns the following user:

```
Snap (users) {
   DELyncz9ZmTtBIKfbNYXtbhUADD2 =     {
       email = "test3@gmail.com";
       "first_name" = test;
       "last_name" = test;
   };
```

How can I get `DELyncz9ZmTtBIKfbNYXtbhUADD2`? I can get the email by using `let email = child.value["email"]` but I can't get the key because it's not a named attribute.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Updated code thanks to Frank's answer. Getting `ambiguous use of key`

```
query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.key)

            if snapshot.exists() {
                print("user exists")

                for child in snapshot.children {
                    print(child.key)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a query at a location, the result will be a list of the matching children. Even if there is only a single matching item, the result will be a list of one child.

You're printing the key of all resulting children. Since there is no single result, the SDK prints the key of the location/collection that you queried: `users`.

What you're likely looking for is to loop over the matching children and print their keys:

```
let query = usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email)
query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print(child.key)
    }
})
```

Comment: Figured it out! Had to just do `let key = child.key as String`. Thanks again!!