# How to properly use queryOrderedByValue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function written in Swift that fetch the leaderboard and then shows it to the user :

```
@IBAction func onShowLeaderboardTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let leaderboardDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("scores").queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 5)

        leaderboardDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("leaderboard snapshot:" ,snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }
```

The problem is that when I fetch it, it gaves me the following list :

```
 Ben = 9;
 Gabriela = 12;
 Ivailo = 7;
 Petar = 10;
 Vania = 10;
```

It shows me the first five players, but then it lists them alphabetically. Since this is not a big problem I wonder if there is a way to order them by the value.

These are the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "scores": {
      ".indexOn": ".value"
    }
  }
}
```

And the DB is organized as follows:

```
  matchrooms:
  users: 
  scores:
>      Ben: 9
>      Dimitar: 7
>      Gabriela: 12
>      Ishest: 6
>      Ivailo: 7
>      Ivan: 5
>      Marina: 3
>      Pesho: 3
>      Petar: 10
>      Rosen: 6
>      Vania: 10
>      Yasen: 2
```

So, my question is how to properly use the `queryOrderedByValue()` to retrieve the first five players and list them by the points they've scored?

Comment: So first off - this is a bad way to structure your firebase data, you should have a node name generated by childByAutoId, with child nodes of name: some name  and   score:  some score. Then you can query those nodes and sort by name or score etc.  As it is, you are sorting byValue which is exactly what you are getting - B)en,  G)abriela, I)vailo  (B, G, I, P V).

Comment: i know it's a bad way, if you noticed, i have users node where they are registered with the childByAutoId func. the list i generated is just to play around with firebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you fire a query against Firebase, it returns the keys of the items that match your query, the value of those items and the relative order of the items in the result. If you listen for a .Value event, all three of these are combined into a single FIRDataSnapshot.

But when you then either ask for the `value` property of that snapshot *or* print that snapshot as one block, the data is converted into a Dictionary. Since a dictionary can only contain keys and values, the ordering of the items is lost at that point. And as it turns out, the dictionary then prints the items ordered by their key.

To get the items in order, you should iterate over them using `snapshot.children`:

```
leaderboardDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print(child.key)
    }
}, withCancel: nil)
```

Also see:

- [Firebase snapshot.key not returning actual key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581193/firebase-snapshot-key-not-returning-actual-key/37581936#37581936)
- [Firebase getting data in order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168370/209103)
- [Firebase queryOrderedByChild() method not giving sorted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222128/firebase-queryorderedbychild-method-not-giving-sorted-data/39229537#39229537)

Comment: thank you, it helps me, I have to use snap.value. now I had tried "snap.children" which works fine. In a same query snap.value return unsorted data snap.children return sorted data

Answer (score 0):

Change the structure

```
scores
  -YUijia099sma
    name: "Ben"
    score: 9
  -Yij9a9jsddd
    name: "Dimitar"
    score: 7
```

then

```
@IBAction func onShowLeaderboardTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let leaderboardDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("scores")
                           .queryOrdered(byChild: "score")
                           .queryLimited(toLast: 5)

        leaderboardDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("leaderboard snapshot:" ,snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }
```

*typing on my iPad so it's not tested and the syntax may not be perfect