# Swift: Converting snapshot value in Firebase database to objects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and swift in general, and I was really confused on how to access information from a firebase database. So basically, I put in this data into my database:[image: my database]

I did all the setup and everything in xcode. However, I've been clueless on how to access this data? I have a model like this:
[image]

I looked through the firebase documentation and it seems you can get a NSDictionary from the snapshot.value, so that's what I did here:

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
var handle:FIRDatabaseHandle!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    ref?.child("series").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dict1 = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let value1 = dict1?.allValues
        for i in 0...(snapshot.childrenCount - 1)
        {
            //???
        }
    })
```

But as far as I know, NSDictionary isn't an array of objects, and you can't call an index and a property from the object at that index, like arrayofobjects[3].property, so I want to transfer it with for loops to an array of objects of type Model so that I can use the information in my app. Is that how you're supposed to do it? How do I transfer it to an array of objects when you can't take an index of NSDictionary?

Comment: 1. Why post some of your code as images instead of as text? Post all relevant code as text. 2. Why use `NSDictionary` in Swift? Use a Swift dictionary instead.

Comment: @rmaddy what's the difference?

Comment: The difference with what?

Comment: I'd wait converting to a dictionary as long as possible. First access the collection of children with `snapshot.children` and loop over it like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37581936/209103). Then get access to each individual property with `snapshot.value`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you can access each individual property in the children? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Firebase has great [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), so just save your time and just read it.

Comment: @Jurasic I read that, it just made me more confused.