# Swift 3 Firebase retrieving key and passing to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've spend hours looking at identical questions but none of the answers I've found are helping this issue. Simple app retrieves data from `Firebase` Database and passes to another view controller from the tableview.  The main data will pass through but I can't edit the information without an identifying "key" which I tried to set as `childByAutoID()` but then changed to a `timestamp`.  Regardless of the method, all I get is the entries info not the actual key itself.

```
func loadData() {
    self.itemList.removeAll()
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    ref.child(userID!).child("MyStuff").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



        if let todoDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,todoElement) in todoDict {



                let todo = TheItems()



                todo.itemName = todoElement["itemName"] as? String
                todo.itemExpires = todoElement["itemExpires"] as? String
                todo.itemType = todoElement["itemType"] as? String



                self.itemList.append(todo)

                print (snapshot.key);

            }



        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Comment: show picture database and what key you want to retrieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase snapshot.key not returning actual key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581193/firebase-snapshot-key-not-returning-actual-key)

Comment: Additionally, you could just add the key into your data when you upload it. So you could do let key =  todoElement["key"] as? String

Comment: under the uid/"MyStuff"/  there is a childbyAutoID and then itemName/ItemExpires/ItemType.  I'm trying to retrieve the childByAutoId number  but .key returns "MyStuff"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

```
Uid: {
    MyStuff: {
        AutoID: {
            itemName: “Apocalypse”,
            itemExpires: “December 21, 2012”,
            itemType: “Catastrophic”
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would query like this:

```
ref.child(userID!).child("MyStuff").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {    
        let child = child as? DataSnapshot
        let key = child?.key as? String

        if let todoElement = child?.value as? [String: Any] {
            let todo = TheItems()
            todo.itemName = todoElement["itemName"] as? String
            todo.itemExpires = todoElement["itemExpires"] as? String
            todo.itemType = todoElement["itemType"] as? String

            self.itemList.append(todo)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

Additionally, like I said in my comment you can just upload the key with the data if you’re using  `.updateChildValues()`. Example:

```
let key = ref.child("userID!").childByAutoId().key
let feed = ["key": key,
         “itemName”: itemName] as [String: Any]

let post = ["\(key)" : feed]

ref.child("userID").child("MyStuff").updateChildValues(post) // might want a completionBlock
```

Then you can get the key the same way you are getting the rest of the values. So your new data would look like this:

```
Uid: {
    MyStuff: {
        AutoID: {
            itemName: “Apocalypse”,
            itemExpires: “December 21, 2012”,
            itemType: “Catastrophic”,
            key: “autoID”
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I cannot express my appreciation enough!  Just a quick question to add on..  When it comes to editing an item, would you suggest a separate ViewController to handle the editing or somehow rig that VC that adds an item to also edit it?  Thanks again!  You're awesome!

Comment: Adding another viewController to edit depends on the UI you are going for. Does it make sense to change screens to edit data? If the data is a simple list in a tableView it might make more sense to edit it right there on the same screen. If it's more elaborate then a separate screen to edit information makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The key you are trying to look for is located in the iterator of your for loop

Inside your if-let, try to do this:

```
for (key,todoElement) in todoDict {
    print(key) // this is your childByAutoId key 
}
```

This should solve the problem. Otherwise show us a screen of your database structure

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really appreciate it!