# How can I pass a Post Id to a Comments VC - Swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble sending the postid to comments vc so that I can save it in Firebase.

I am following a tutorial online where we are building [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OofOe.jpg) architecture on Firebase however when I send the data to Firebase it is not capturing the postId as seen on[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXYYl.png). I'm obviously missing something. Would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light as to what my mistake could be. Below I'll put the Comments View Controller function where I send the data to Firebase.

```
  @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let commentsReference = ref.child("comments")
    let newCommentId = commentsReference.childByAutoId().key
    let newCommentReference = commentsReference.child(newCommentId)

    //current user information
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    let currentUserId = currentUser.uid
    newCommentReference.setValue(["userid": currentUserId, "commentText": commentTextField.text!]) { (error, ref) in

        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
            }
        let postCommentRef = Database.database().reference().child("post-comments").child(self.postIdNew).child(newCommentId)
        postCommentRef.setValue(true, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        })
        self.empty()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

This is how I'm supposed to get the postId reference from the Home View Controller.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "commentSegue" {
        let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        let postId = sender as! String
        commentVC.postIdNew = postId
    }
}
```

Here are my collection view extensions

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if collectionView == self.lostCollectionView {

        return posts.count
    }

    if collectionView == self.foundCollectionView {

        return newPostsFound.count

    }

    if collectionView == self.adoptionCollectionView {

        return postsadoption.count
    }

    else {

        return 0
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch collectionView {

    case lostCollectionView:

        let lostcell: LostCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Lostcell", for: indexPath) as! LostCollectionViewCell

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        lostcell.post = post
        lostcell.user = user

        //Make TextView Clickable
        lostcell.phoneLostTextView.isEditable = false;
        lostcell.phoneLostTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.phoneNumber

        //Make Comments View Clickable
        lostcell.homeVC = self
        return lostcell


    case foundCollectionView:
        let foundcell: FoundCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Foundcell", for: indexPath) as! FoundCollectionViewCell

        let post = newPostsFound[indexPath.row]
        foundcell.post = post

        //Make TextView Clickable
        foundcell.phoneFoundTextView.isEditable = false;
        foundcell.phoneFoundTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.phoneNumber
        return foundcell

    case adoptionCollectionView:
        let adoptioncell: AdoptionCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Adopotioncell", for: indexPath) as! AdoptionCollectionViewCell

        let post = postsadoption[indexPath.row]
        adoptioncell.post = post

        //Make TextView Clickable
        adoptioncell.phoneAdoptionTextView.isEditable = false;
        adoptioncell.phoneAdoptionTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.phoneNumber
        return adoptioncell

    default:
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    switch collectionView {

    case lostCollectionView:

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "lostSelectedViewController") as? LostSelectedViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        vc?.posts = posts[indexPath.row]
        break

    case foundCollectionView:
       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foundSelectedViewController") as? FoundSelectedViewController
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        vc?.posts = newPostsFound[indexPath.row]
        break

    case adoptionCollectionView:
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "adoptionSelectedViewController") as? AdoptionSelectedViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        vc?.posts = postsadoption[indexPath.row]
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    func commentsViewPressed() {
        print("Hola")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "commentSegue", sender: self)

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my mistake was nowhere here. My mistake was that my snapshot.key was not retreiving the childByAutoId so when I ran the query it gave me a list of matching children and since there was no single result, the SDK prints the key of the location/collection that you queried: posts.

All I had to do was to retrieve the childByAutoId I had to use this line:

```
 let key = childSnapshot.key as String
```

I found my answer in this stackoverflow question --> [Firebase snapshot.key not returning actual key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581193/firebase-snapshot-key-not-returning-actual-key)

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like its in this code

```
let postId = sender as! String
commentVC.postIdNew = postId
```

`Sender` refers to the object that initiated the segue, so likely a button or TableViewCell (see apples docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare)

You need to replace `sender as! String` with the value of the postId that you are trying to set. I assume that you can get that from somewhere on the first view controller.

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for the quick reply. The thing is that I have three collection views. How could I grab the postId? I'm new at swift and don't have a lot of experience with this topic

Comment: If you can post more code from your controller with the collection views, then that would help. Particularly you datasources for them.

Comment: sure let me add them!

Comment: Where does the `sendButtonPressed` method live?

Comment: in  the Comment View Controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see where `commentsViewPressed()` is being called. It's different to when you tap on a collectionviewcell?

Comment: hmmm haven't called it, but then why is the segue being performed?

Comment: I assume you have set up the segue in the Storyboard, which will call `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` as a result. This means that you CollectionViewCell will be the `sender`. So you could do something like `let cell = sender as? FoundCollectionViewCell` then `let postID = cell.post.postID`

Comment: The only thing with this is that you would need to have all three cells classes to inherit from a base cell class that has a `post` property.

Comment: I could maybe do that with a switch. Could I send you an email?

Comment: Yeah that's fine.

Comment: what's your email :D ?